# Reading zlib stream into dynamically allocated buffer

Tags: c, zlib

I am trying to read a gz file into a char buffer which should resize depending on how big the file is.

```
  gzFile infile = gzopen(infile_name, "rb");
  
  char *buf      = malloc(256);
  int total_read = 0;
  int incr_read  = 0;
  
  do {
    incr_read   = gzread(infile + total_read, buf, 256);
    total_read += incr_read;
    buf         = realloc(buf, total_read + 256);
  } while (incr_read > 0);
```

This stops immediately for some reason, only reading the first 256 bytes. There is no way it reached the end of the file, because it is 1.3 kB in size (compressed). How could I continue reading the rest of the file?

I am relatively new to C so there is likely something obvious I overlooked, but I have not been able to find a solution elsewhere.

Comment: `infile + total_read` Er.... why are you doing that? It's a wonder you're not getting a segfault.

Comment: @Shawn I'm not sure of a better way to do it. I'm pretty sure it should always be covered by realloc though, because allocates 256 bytes beyond whatever `total_read` is

Comment: It makes as much sense as `fgets(buf, 256, stdin + total_read)` would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to `gzread()` should be a `gzFile` handle but you pass `infile + total_read` for some reason instead of just `infile`.

Answer (score 1):

I was shifting the file pointer instead of the buffer pointer, which was why it wasn't working. it should have been `gzread(infile, buf + total_read, 256);`

Answer (score 0):

The `gzFile` is an opaque pointer to a struct that contains a bunch of internal state information, so you shouldn't do any arithmetic on it. The first argument to `gzread` should be the same for every iteration of the loop.